# ¿Cómo meto datos json desde python sin que me resetee

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Muy buenas,
tengo este código en python para pasar datos a json:

```
data = {}
data['customers'] = []

data['customers'].append({
    'name': tag ,
    'pass': pwd,
    'ip': ip ,})

with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

El problema viene cuándo quiero enviar datos varias veces.
Al meter los datos por segunda vez se me resetean los primeros.
Cómo puedo ir almacenando datos sin que se me borren los primeros?

Comment: Podrías probar abriendo el archivo en modo "append", es decir : `with open('data.json', 'a') as file:`. Esto te permitirá ir agregando información, lo que no te asegura es que el archivo finalmente sea un json válido

Comment: Te recomiendo que cuando no uses el fichero data.json lo cierres con "file.close()". Lo que hace es cerrar el archivo por completo, terminar con los recursos de uso y a la vez liberándolos.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución:

```
data = {}
data['customers'] = []

data['customers'].append({
    'name': tag ,
    'pass': pwd,
    'ip': ip ,})

with open('data.json', 'a') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

file.close()
```

Resultado de "**data.json**":

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "ip": "ip", 
            "name": "tag", 
            "pass": "pwd"
        }
    ]
}{
    "customers": [
        {
            "asda": "asdasd", 
            "name": "fad", 
            "ip": "adsad"
        }
    ]
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: El problema es que el fichero JSON que generas de ese modo no es JSON válido. Si lo intentas leer de nuevo romperá el parser. Puedes arreglarlo si pones al principio del fichero `[`, al final del mismo `]`, y añades al final de cada JSON volcado (salvo el último) una coma `, `. Aunque para eso más valdría acunular los diccionarios en una lista python y luego volcar al fichero json la lista.